# Is there an email notification for crash reports in iTunes Connect and Google Play?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store-connect

I want to be notified on crash reports automatically by iTunes Connect and Google Play developer console. I did not find any feature like this in iTunes Connect or Google Play. Some  searches on Google lead to third party tools like:

[bugsense.com](http://www.bugsense.com)

[crashlytics.com](http://www.crashlytics.com)

[crittercism.com](http://www.crittercism.com)

[hockeyapp.net](http://www.hockeyapp.net)

But is there a way to be notified on standard crash reports in iTunes Connect and Google Play automatically without integrating any of these third party devices? It would be nice to get informed as soon as problem arises instead of looking up itc and the console every day or week.

Comment: You'd think this would be a pretty simple and built-in feature of both of these stores. Right now I have to manually check the Play store for any crashes or ANRs. They don't even highlight the menu item when there are new crashes...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding iTunes Connect: There is no such feature.

In addition, iTunes Connect will only provide you a subset of crash reports due to most people not allowing crash reports and analytics data to be send to Apple and iTunes Connect only showing reports, if there are a minimum number of similar reports. The exact logic is unknown, but most developers rarely find any crash reports in there at all.

As an example: My own free app "WorldView by webcams.travel" (latest version available since 4th December 2013) shows `0` (zero) crash reports in iTunes Connect. HockeyApp on the other side shows `26`.

The single major benefit iTunes Connect has currently: you also get reports for cases where the app got killed by the watchdog (e.g. startup took longer than 10 seconds, main thread is blocked or the app allocated too much memory).

Since I don't have any Android apps, I can not comment on the exact behavior of Google Play.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of HockeyApp.

Comment: @Kemi: Out of curiosity, why did you name it **Hockey**App?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play now allows this feature:

1. Log into the Google Play console
2. Navigate to Settings > Preferences
3. Scroll to the 'Notifications from Play Console' section
4. Check the 'Email' box under 'ANRs and crashes'